# StartAsync method of Dialog Inheriting BestMatchDialog Not Invoking

Tags: botframework

I have created on BestMatchDialog in my bot, and i want to do some task in its StartAsync method. but problem is that the startasync method not get hit of dialog which implementing BestMatchDialog.
my code is as below

```
[Serializable]
public class GreetingsDialog : BestMatchDialog<object>
{
    [AsyncStateMachine(typeof(BestMatchDialog<object>))]
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            //Some code to execute
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    [BestMatch(
        new string[] {
                    "test", "test1", "test2", 
                })]
    public async Task Test(IDialogContext context, string messageText)
    {
            string[] Answers =
                { "Hello there. Test",
                  "just going to say hi",
                  "hello my friend",
                  "heyya !!"
                };

            int index = new Random().Next(0, (Answers.Length - 1));
            await context.PostAsync(Answers[index]);
            context.Done(true);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this has to do with the inheritance, try using this

`public override async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)`

instead of this

`public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)`

Comment: yes it worked,Thanks. and I forwarded context to MessageReceived method like this in startAsync method context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);